# Change Magento2 Home Page Text

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I was wondering how I would change the t`ext / phtml` on the home page. Specifically where it says "CMS homepage content goes here." For other blocks I am able to override the phtml, but this one I am having some trouble figuring it out.

Answer (score 2):

Home page in Magento is CMS page stored in DB.

You can go to Admin > Content > Pages and edit "Home Page" page.

Also you can change default controller responsible  for home page in

> system configuration GENERAL > Default Pages > Default Web URL.

for example: set to `customer/account/create/`

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do this programmatically. For example if I want to just load a phtml file in there?

Comment: Actually never mind. I see the fix. Sorry about that. Thanks!